# Have different version of rails website for different language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization

I have a rails app which is localized in multiple languages. Some time for the localization to complete it takes more time after the some enhancements are done in english language. So it was decided to release the latest version of the website in english language. and retain the older version for other non-english languages. So that the release dates need not be pushed till localization were complete. I am not sure how to implemented. Any idea about how should i go about doing it will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*seeing your comments to Chubas's answer* You can bind to `http://website.com` simple application which will check user's locale (or whatever else) and redirect him to `http://website.com/en` or `http://website.com/int`, each running a separate application.

It may seem not very pretty, but it's simple and many enterprise websites actually use it. With a bit more setupping you can even have configurable names like `fr`, `de`, etc. instead of `int` (all pointing to the same application).

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole [Internationalization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) (abbrev. i18n) module available in Rails. You can easily switch languages this way, or serve them separately based on some parameter (say, the URL).

Comment: say for eg. i am changing the UI completely. i want to have the new UI for english. and keep the old UI for other languages? is that possible?

Comment: If for UI you mean the content and texts that appear, yes. If for UI you mean a totally different interface, it is also possible, but will require more work, is not straightforward. Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: for eg. i make lot of enhancements to a site. (adding new features etc)both UI and server-side. And want this updated version seen only in english. for other languages. old version only should be shown. I want to know what is the better way of doing this.